# I can't get Python to sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to create a simple button delay on a Raspberry Pi. I have GPIO output 16 connected to an LED and input 36 as the button. I am trying to only press the button quickly and it keeps the LED on for 10 seconds.

This is the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(36):
        GPIO.output(16,False)
    else:
        GPIO.output(16,True)
        sleep(10)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention having a capacitor on the switch, so I presume you haven't debounced the switch. It may help to do so. Even though you physically press the button once, if you were to look at the waveform on an oscilloscope, it would be seen as multiple presses and that could be affecting code execution here, in addition to the time.sleep issue mentioned above. Take a look at this page for a bunch of ways to do that:

https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/

This video shows something similar to what you're doing and not working as expected and then debounces using the time.sleep command:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3pBtFAynoM

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing the issue is that you're using `sleep()` without specifying the namespace.

You have 2 solutions here:

First is replacing the `import time` by this:

```
from time import sleep
```

Second is replacing every `sleep()` call by `time.sleep()`, e.g.:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(36):
        GPIO.output(16,False)
    else:
        GPIO.output(16,True)
        time.sleep(10) # changed line
    time.sleep(0.1) # changed line
```

If you want to better understand, I suggest you take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: Hi ImranD, I have tried this and it still doesn't wait as id hoped it would.

Comment: Hello, I'd need more details then. What's happening? Is there an error, a traceback I could read?

Comment: At the moment when I press on a push to make button on a breadboard, the PI reads this connection, and sends a signal out of pin 16 lighting an LED. I am trying to get it to once the LED is lit to stay on for 10 seconds even when the button is opened. The circuit has been made in a way for the LED to light without the switch, i just cant get it to stay on.